# IF THEN ELSE MariaDb

Tags: if-statement, mariadb

I'm trying to write a simple 'IF' statement on MariaDb but I stumbled on the basics.

This is my code:

```
SELECT @variable := `value` FROM configuration WHERE key = 'key'
```

this seems to work, but can a variable declared in this way be used in a if ?

```
IF @variable = "foo" THEN
    UPDATE ...
    UPDATE ...
    DELETE ...
ELSE
    UPDATE ...
END IF;
```

I'm forced to put this code only in a procedure ? Most of the code I read put all this inside a procedure but in the official documentation [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/if/) there is nothing about it.

When I try to run this script inside phpMyAdmin I get:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF @variable = "foo" THEN
    UPDATE tags SET ....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [if statement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/if-statement/) can be used [outside of stored procedures](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/using-compound-statements-outside-of-stored-programs/).

PHPMyAdmin apprently has a [delimiter as part of its UI](https://www.agustinvillalba.com/create-triggers-phpmyadmin/).

The alternative is:

```
   UPDATE  ... WHERE @variable = "foo" 
   UPDATE  ... WHERE @variable = "foo" 
   DELETE  ... WHERE @variable = "foo" 
   UPDATE  ... WHERE @variable != "foo"
```